# multi store, manual activation account with prestashop

Tags: prestashop, account, manual, activation, multistore

I use multi-store option with prestashop. I would like to pass customers in the second store to manual activation after registration.

Actually I set `$customer->active = 0;` in authentication.php.

all registration customer in both websites are inactive after registration.

Is there a way to set `$customer->active = 0;` just for one website.

I think to get `shop_id` but I don't know how to develop my idea.

Comment: What is the prestashop version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Prestashop **1.6** :

You can get the `id_shop` with the [Context](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+Context+Object) object.

So, I think you can do something like this :

If you know the `id_shop` (suppose the `id_shop` = 1)

```
if (Context::getContext()->shop->id == 1) {
    $customer->active = 0;
} else {
    $customer->active = 1;
}
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Updated answer to get the `id_shop` from context because the Customer object doesn't handle it until it's added.

**RE-EDIT**

In the `Customer` class (/classes/Customer.php) customize the `add()` function.

Add this line around the line 212 (after the "last_passwd_gen" declaration) :

```
$this->active = ($this->id_shop == 3) ? false : true;
```

But the best solution for you is to create an [override](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingaclass) of the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I use prestashop 1.6.1.2 but it doesn't work 
I know the id_shop from the database
I added in  controllers/front/AuthController.php
if (Context::getContext()->shop->id == 3) {
    $customer->active = 0;
} else {
    $customer->active = 1;
}
but after the registration customers are still inactive in the both website

Comment: You're welcome. I re-edit the answer. The file to customize is `classes/Customer.php`. Good luck.